# React Select with firestore array

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-select

I'm trying to display a react-select with options equal to Firestore data but I get only one option with all the array. How can I show the options individually? Thanks.

Well, this is my options from react-select:

```
  const options = [{ value: read01, label: read01 }];
```

and this is where I retrieve the date:

```
  const retrieveNetwork13 = async () => {
    try {
      //const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "cities"));

      const q = query(collection(db, "schedule"));

      const qq = query(q, where("uid2", "==", uid3));

      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(qq);

      setRead01(querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().schedule2));
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hi Andres. When asking a question on Stack Overflow, it's best to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can allow others to see what the problem is and advise you on how to fix it. In this case, since you are using an external service (Firestore), you should provide an example with dummy data in the same shape as the data you receive from Firestore. Please add some dummy data and some (again, minimal, reproducible) code, and then the community can try to help.

Comment: Hi. I just edit the question. Can you help me, please? Thank you

Comment: You haven't provided a reproducible example (I can't run your code). I think it's enough for me to try writing an answer, but in the future, please provide something like a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) with, I'll emphasize again, *dummy* data so that the example can actually be run.

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin by isolating the key parts of your code. Here, you are using a react setter function to set `read01` to some transformation of your query snapshot (I'm assuming that elsewhere there's code like `const [read01, setRead01] = useState([])`):

```js
setRead01(querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().schedule2));
```

`querySnapshot.docs` appears to be an array of objects, which you are querying for its `data()` and then extracting the property `schedule2`. I can't say what the shape of `schedule2` is from the information you've provided, but let's assume that it's just a `string`. Given all that, you are setting `read01` to an array of strings (the result of `querySnapshot.docs.map`).

Now, let's look at the options you provide to react-select:

```js
const options = [{ value: read01, label: read01 }];
```

You have specified **one and only one** option, for which both the value and label will be `read01`, which we've established is an array of strings. However, `value` and `label` in a react-select options array are intended to be *strings*, not *arrays of strings*. See e.g. the [first example](https://codesandbox.io/s/e4o2n5?module=/example.tsx&file=/docs/data.ts) on the [react-select homepage](https://react-select.com/home). The relevant options array is:

```js
export const colourOptions: readonly ColourOption[] = [
  { value: 'ocean', label: 'Ocean', color: '#00B8D9', isFixed: true },
  { value: 'blue', label: 'Blue', color: '#0052CC', isDisabled: true },
  ...
];
```

See how `value` and `label` are just plain strings?

I think what you probably intended to do is map `read01` into an array of options. Imagine that this is the contents of `read01`:

```js
const read01 = ["option1", "option2", "option3"];
```

Then, we could define `options` as:

```js
const options = read01.map((val) => ({ value: val, label: val }));
```

[Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-xduuzn?file=/example.js) a working sandbox for you to play with.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Is displaying only one optionwith ass the values in firestore. The data in firestore is like this:   schedule2 0 "0:00-1:00".

Comment: Sorry for the poor data but I really need help. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Please update your question as follows: 1) Give an *exact* value for `read01`. Try using `console.log` and pasting in the output. Exact data will allow me to reproduce what you see. 2) Specify *exactly* the desired outcome. Given a value of `read01`, *how many* options do you expect, and what are of *all* of their *exact* desired values?